# Procurar valores de uma Lista e Substituir em outra lista - Python

Tags: python

Estou tentando procurar elementos da lista A na Lista B e substituir por outro valor se este elemento for encontrado. Como posso fazer isso?

```
A = ["Leao" , "Lobo" , "Largarto"]
B = ["Cachorro" , "Leao" , "Cobra" , "Girafa" , "Lobo" , "Largarto"]
```

Substituir elemento de A em B pela palavra "Manga" e o resultado seria

```
C = ["Cachorro" , "Manga" , "Cobra" , "Girafa" , "Manga" , "Manga"]
```

Pesquisando eu só consegui encontrar este código, mas ai eu teria que toda vez escrever o que preciso substituir:

```
B = [item.replace("Leao", "Manga") for item in B]
```

Answer (score 5):

A melhor forma é você percorrer a lista B e para cada valor verificar se ele está em A; se estiver, retornar o valor a ser substituído, senão retornar o próprio valor.

Com compreensão de lista isso fica bastante simples:

```
C = [b if b not in A else 'Manga' for b in B]
```

No trecho `for b in B` você percorre toda a lista B; em `b if b not in A else 'Manga'` você mantém o valor de `b` quando ele não está em A ou "Manga" quando tiver.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra forma de fazer é você criar um dicionário com a `key` sendo o elemento que você substituir e o `value` dessa key o novo elemento:

```py
A = {
# "item na array B":"novo valor",
    "Leao":"Manga" ,
    "Lobo":"Banana" ,
    "Largarto":"Abacaxi"
}
B = ["Cachorro" , "Leao" , "Cobra" , "Girafa" , "Lobo" , "Largarto"]


C = [ (A[item] if item in A else item) for item in B ]

print( C )
# SAIDA DO PRINT:
# ['Cachorro', 'Manga', 'Cobra', 'Girafa', 'Banana', 'Abacaxi']
```

<sup>Veja o codigo funcionando no [ideone](https://ideone.com/P97RdY)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!